# Website shows 'connection is not secure' on Firefox

Tags: wordpress, security, themes

My website shows ‘connection is not secure’ on Firefox when I activate a third party theme. Also, all the forms on this theme says: ‘`This connection is not secure. Logins entered here could be compromised`’.

Default themes are not showing this notification.

The Website is [Indian Amigos](http://www.indianamigos.com/)

The theme I'm using is [QAEngine](https://themeforest.net/item/qaengine-question-and-answer-wordpress-theme/7972399)

Comment: Remove that theme.

Comment: Probably this theme uses SSL (https://) and there is no valid certifikate?

Comment: Please provide a link to, or the name of, the theme that causes this.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your site does not have SSL certificate. To protect the users some browsers are giving warning as and when users give an input. You have to purchase SSL certificate to get rid of the problem and the 'http://' will be replaced by 'https://' . I invite to follow the link for more information. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Insecure_passwords